# Buildout: use a "package" as an entry-point?

Tags: python, buildout

I have a directory named `./foo` in my project which contains an `__init__.py` file, which contains a method named `main()`.

I'd like to use buildout to create an executable which will execute the `main()` method (eg: `./bin/foo`). I've achieved something similar at the "top-level" of my directory structure using the following `buildout.cfg` section:

```
[bar]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
entry-points = bar=bar:main
```

This works fine for my `./bar.py` file, creating an executable `./bin/bar` file. I just can't seem to get it to work for the `./foo/__init__.py` file.

How could I achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, python finds modules and packages via the python path, via the `sys.path` variable. When `buildout` creates scripts in the `bin/` directory, it'll add to the `sys.path` variable, listing all the eggs for the given part.

In order for python to find your `./bar.py` module, or your `./foo` package, the current directory needs to part of python path too. I find it *very* surprising that a `bar.py` module is found for `bin/bar`, while the `./foo` package is not found; clearly the python paths for both parts are different. You can look at the top of the generated `bin/bar` and `bin/foo` scripts to see what paths have been added to `sys.path`.

In any case, you can manually add additional paths to `sys.path` with the `extra-paths` option in the `zc.recipe.egg` part. Any path listed there will end up in your generated script. Simply setting this to `${buildout:directory}` is enough:

```
[foo]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = ${buildout:directory}
entry-points = foo=foo:main
```